# How do you install OpenVZ in Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, openvz

The question says it all - to me, there seems to be a lack of information on how to specifically install the latest OpenVZ kernel on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. Unfortunately for me, that's exactly what I want to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`OpenVZ` is quite out-dated. Linux Container - `LXC` is the way to go if you just want to use isolated containers (OS Level virtualization), the container is in between chroot and a VM.

LXC does not require patches to the kernel, LXC is in the mainline, libvirt support... What's more, OpenVZ containers run on LXC, only config modifications required.

For more information
Official docs https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/lxc.html

Lots of images available:
https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/

Reference
http://www.stgraber.org/2012/05/04/lxc-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

http://www.janoszen.com/2012/06/04/lxc-linux-containers-on-steroids/

Comment: I have received an insane amount of traffic on my site from this answer and as a direct follow up, **I have [written a tutorial](http://www.janoszen.com/2013/06/04/openvz-on-ubuntu-12-04-experimental/) for an experimental procedure to get OpenVZ running on Ubuntu 12.04**. I have recently been in touch with the OpenVZ guys and it's not as dead as we were lead to believe, so I'm working on a more long term solution for OpenVZ on Ubuntu.